# Why does RSACng.SignHash() have a HashAlgorithmName parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

Why does `RSACng.SignHash()` have a `HashAlgorithmName` parameter? It makes sense for the sister method `SignData` but why do we need it for already hashed data?

Consequently, why does `ECDsaCng.SignHash()` not have such a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standards for signatures sometimes involve a format that includes an identifier for the hash algorithm along with the signature itself. For example, see [RSA PKCS #1 version 1.5 signature formatting](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-9.2). The digestInfo structure has a hash algorithm identifier along with the hash itself.

> 2. Encode the algorithm ID for the hash function and the hash
>    value into an ASN.1 value of type DigestInfo (see
>    Appendix A.2.4) with the DER, where the type DigestInfo has
>    the syntax
>
>    ```
>           DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
>               digestAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
>               digest OCTET STRING
>           }
>    ```
>
>    The first field identifies the hash function and the second
>    contains the hash value.  Let T be the DER encoding of the
>    DigestInfo value (see the notes below), and let tLen be the
>    length in octets of T.

Note that RSA-PSS does not include the hash algorithm identifier in the message format, nor does ECDSA. Since signatures are often part of higher-level cryptographic objects like certificates, algorithm identifiers may be present in those objects instead.

Comment: Thank you, do you know by chance if this is true for RSA PSS as well?

Comment: @D.R. It appears that RSA PSS does **not** include the hash algorithm identifier. My previous comment was incorrect.

Comment: RSA-PSS doesn't include it in the output, but the hash algorithm to SignHash/VerifyHash controls what hash is used for MGF-1, so the hash algorithm name input is still required (and has to be the same at VerifyHash as it was for SignHash)

Comment: @bartonjs: Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that these two algorithms are just completely different.

RSA needs to know what algorithm was used for producing the hash to calculate the signature (specifically in PSS), and a padding mode.

ECDsa does not need to know the hash, it always produces the signature in the same way. You do need to pass in the `HashAlgorithmName` for verifying the signature.